# Comparing an array while mapping it to JSX elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that looks like this one(it has more items inside of it, but the structure is the same):

```
 [
        {
            "users": [
               "speciality": "surgery",
                {
                   "name": "John",
                   "location": "USA",
                    "age": "34",
                },
               {
                    "name": "John",
                   "location": "California",
                    "address": "Silk Road 123"
                },
               {
                   "name": "Jane",
                   "last-name": "Edmus"
                   "location": "USA"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
```

I´m trying to map this array in such a way that, if the name property is equal in two objects, it should get mapped as only one p tag with many locations  appearing behind a "see more "tag". This is what I currently have, which doesn´t work:

```
mapArray = () => {
    const test= this.state.test;
    return test.map(i => 
       i.users.map((user,index) =>
       <div>
         <p>{i.speciality}</p>
         user.name[index] === user.name[index + 1] 
             ? <p>{user}</p> <p>See more></p> <p>{user.location}} 
             : <p>{user}<p>{user.location}</p>
       </div>
}
```

Comment: Two things come up to my mind, first the code will error out because inside users there is a `prop` named `speciality`, second you should find a way to `group` the users by their `name` in order to achieve what you want. Cheers, sigfried.

Comment: 1. That isn't a valid array. 2. Calling `map()` will return an array of the same length, which isn't what you want. You can simply use `forEach()` to iterate over the array and build an array of arrays based on the location, or use some `reduce()` magic (less readable but shorter).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a native js function but one easy option is to use lodash groupby. Below is roughly how it could be done with lodash (unverified code):

```
// we first need to group the names for each object in the test array
getGroups = test => {
    return test.map(item => {
       item.groupedUsers = _.groupBy(item.users, user => user.name)
       return item
    })
}

// then we check and iterate through grouped data
render() {
  const groupedData = getGroups(this.state.test)
  return (
      <div>
         { groupedData.map(item => {
             return Object.keys(item.groupedUsers).map(user => 
              <div>
                { item.groupedUsers[user].length > 1 ? <p>{user}</p> <p>See more></p> : <p>{user}</p> } 
              </div> ) 
          } )

         }
      </div>
  )
}
```